# How to set up Netbeans 8 for .sass files instead of .scss files

Tags: sass, netbeans

I'm trying to get Netbeans 8 to use .sass files instead of .scss files. I'm working together on a project with others and tey are using .sass files extensions. I got Netbeans to compile .scss files on save but when using .sass files nothing happens. Is there anyway to do this in Netbeans? Otherwise I have to go outside of the Netbeans IDE every time I want to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not yet possible in Netbeans to watch .sass files. But I managed to get it working using the command line `sass -watch` command, as this also watches .sass files.